# How to set to disable browser cache in spring boot?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, caching, browser-cache

i want set disable browser cache(cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0) in spring boot.

my env

```
  spring-boot: 2.1.2
  spring-security: not use
```

i searched if i want to set response headers's cache-control: no-cache,
just add at 'application.yml'.

like this

```
spring.resources.cache:
  cachecontrol:
    max-age: 0
    no-cache: true
    no-store: true
    cache-private: true
```

or

```
spring.resources.chain.cache: false
```

but it does not worked.

i cant show cache-control header in my chrome browser's response headers.

in spring-framework, i just set

```
<mvc:mapping path="/**"/>
    <bean id="webContentInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
         <property name="cacheSeconds" value="0"/>
         <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
         <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
         <property name="useCacheControlNoStore" value="true"/>
    </bean>
</mvc:interceptor>
```

**how to set disable browser cache in spring boot without spring security?**

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

try by adding this line in application.properties

```
spring.cache.type=NONE
```

Comment: thanks, but I added the code, it still response headers does not show up 'cache-control' or 'pragma' header.